# Iterate through List to another List and run logic

Tags: c#, list, addrange

I need to create a scheduling application that will pull information from an Access query that sorts with decending priority and ascending dates to get the order to add and then iterates through the query by rows then columns (down first step then down second step then down third step) and add them to a single `ArrayList`.

The fields are

```
Priority    DueDate     JobsSequence1   ProcTime    JobsSequence2   ProcTime    ...

       1    4/28/2015    Job1Milling1          1         Job1CNC2          1    Job1Drilling3   1   
       1    4/28/2015    Job2Milling1          1    Job2Drilling2          1     Job2Milling3   1   
       0    4/29/2015   Job3Drilling1          1         Job3CNC2          1     Job3Milling3   1
```

I need them to be added to an `ArrayList` in a `ConsoleApp` or `Windows Form` to calculate a schedule. I would like to use the logic of.

- Initialize `ArrayList` by using processing time.
- Check previous Job step
- Check previous Workstation step
- Take max of Job step and Workstation step and add processing time

To come up with:
This list is an example of what the `ArrayList` will look like with the logic already ran.

```
              Job       EndTime

     Job1Milling1             1
     Job2Milling1             2
    Job3Drilling1             1
         Job1CNC2             2
    Job2Drilling2             3
         Job3CNC2             3
    Job1Drilling3             4
     Job2Milling3             4
     Job3Milling3             5
      Job1Finish4             5
      Job2Finish4             6
      Job3Finish4             7
```

The numbers from the new `ArrayList` will be added to the start of the day at 8am. So the first job would end at 9am. Second job will end at 10am. Third will end at 9am.

My questions are, How do I add the query to an arraylist like the way I have it in the example? How do I then calculate the end hours by running through my logic from above? Lastly, How would I export it back out to a report that shows the above list with Start time (end time minus proc time) and End time.

***Update***
I attempted part of it and I was able to use a little linq.

I am not sure on how to add specific fields in Jobs to JobListOrder using .AddRange(). I would like to place all of the Workstations into one column and reference the JobNum and ProcTime to be able to calculate the EndTime. Like the table above.

Next, I am unsure on how to check the Max(Max of Current Jobnum (JobListOrder.EndTime) && Max of Current Workstation (JobListOrder.EndTime)) then add ProcTime

Example, Take all of Job1 and take max then take all of Milling and take max. Take the max of those two and add ProcTime.

```
class Program
{
    //Add class
    public class Jobs
    {
        public int JobNum { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
        public string WS1 { get; set; }
        public int Seq1 { get; set; }
        public string WS2 { get; set; }
        public int Seq2 { get; set; }
        public string WS3 { get; set; }
        public int Seq3 { get; set; }
        public string WS4 { get; set; }
        public int Seq4 { get; set; }
    }
    public class JobListOrder
    {
        public int JobNum { get; set; }
        public string Workstation { get; set; }
        public int Sequence { get; set; }
        public int ProcTime { get; set; }
        public int EndHour { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    }
    // Create data source for testing
    static List<Jobs> jobs = new List<Jobs>
    {
        new Jobs {JobNum = 1, Priority = 0, DueDate = DateTime.Today, WS1 = "Milling", Seq1 = 1, WS2 = "CNC", Seq2 = 1, WS3 = "Drilling", Seq3 = 1, WS4 = "Finish", Seq4 = 1 },
        new Jobs {JobNum = 2, Priority = 0, DueDate = DateTime.Today, WS1 = "Milling", Seq1 = 2, WS2 = "Drilling", Seq2 = 1, WS3 = "Milling", Seq3 = 1, WS4 = "Finish", Seq4 = 1 },
        new Jobs {JobNum = 3, Priority = 1, DueDate = DateTime.Today, WS1 = "Drilling", Seq1 = 1, WS2 = "CNC", Seq2 = 1, WS3 = "Milling", Seq3 = 1, WS4 = "Finish", Seq4 = 1 }
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Sort by Priority then Due Date
        IEnumerable<Jobs> jobquery =
            from jobnum in jobs
            orderby jobnum.Priority descending
            orderby jobnum.DueDate ascending
            select jobnum;
        //Write to new list that sorts in job order
        List<Jobs> JobORder = new List<Jobs>;
        foreach ()
        //Calculate the EndTime in JobsOrder

        // ****Take Max(Max of Current Jobnum (JobListOrder.EndTime) && Max of Current Workstation (JobListOrder.EndTime)) then add ProcTime****


        //Select Jobs with "Milling" in JobListOrder
        IEnumerable<JobListOrder> MillingQuery =
            from jobnum1 in jobquery
            where jobnum1.Workstation == "Milling"
            select jobnum1;
        //Select Jobs with "Drilling" in JobListOrder
        IEnumerable<JobListOrder> DrillingQuery =
            from jobnum2 in jobquery
            where jobnum2.Workstation == "Drilling"
            select jobnum2;
        //Select Jobs with "CNC" in JobListOrder
        IEnumerable<JobListOrder> CNCQuery =
            from jobnum3 in jobquery
            where jobnum3.Workstation == "CNC"
            select jobnum3;
        //Select Jobs with "Finish" in JobListOrder
        IEnumerable<JobListOrder> FinishQuery =
            from jobnum4 in jobquery
            where jobnum4.Workstation == "Finish"
            select jobnum4;

        //foreach (Jobs jobnum1 in FinishQuery)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("Job number is {0}, Station ID is {1}, Proc Time is {2}, Date is {3}", jobnum1.JobNum, jobnum1.WS1, jobnum1.Seq1, jobnum1.DueDate.AddHours(jobnum1.Seq1));

        //}
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`, it's a holdover from .NET 1.1. Use a generic `List` instead. It sounds like what you actually should be doing is creating a class to contain those properties, then creating a `List` of that class. From there, you can use LINQ to query and filter against that list.

Comment: Thanks. I attempted it with the List and was able to get a little further. I am still having a little trouble understanding how to make the original list and put it into the new list to create an order. The next problem I am having is using the logic I have up top in creating endtimes. Thank you for your help.